# How to calculate the Discrete Fourier Transform Sample Frequencies using Tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, fft

I'm new to using tensorflow.

I'm building a custom loss function that needs to calculate "Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies". I can do this calculation using the python library `numpy.fft.fftfreq` but I would like to use only tensorflow. I see that there is difficulty accepting numpy functions in the implementation.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html

Does anyone know any way to do `numpy.fft.fftfreq` in tensorflow?

Comment: this might help  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft

Comment: I know there is a fft in tensorflow. But there is no fft.fftfreq :(